# How can I monitor a flow over wireless connection?

Tags: tcl, simulation, wireless, ns2

I am trying to monitor a tcp flow using flow monitor. attach-fmon wants link object which is not available in wireless connections. How can I solve this problem ? Are there any other solutions ?

My code is here
http://pastebin.com/f59241692

I got this error message

```
eid@eid-laptop:~/code/ns2/noisy$ ns mixed.tcl
num_nodes is set 3
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
invalid command name ""
    while executing
"$lnk attach-monitors $isnoop $osnoop $dsnoop $fm"
    (procedure "_o3" line 5)
    (Simulator attach-fmon line 5)
    invoked from within
"$ns_ attach-fmon $wllink $fmon"
    (file "mixed.tcl" line 182)
```

Comment: You need to indent examples with four spaces or use <pre></pre> to avoid the wiki Markdown syntax

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark (http://wireshark.org) replaced ethereal in 2006, and is a free, open-source network protocol analyser. It can capture, and analyse data from pretty much any network interface, and will allow you to filter on the communication path of interest by filtering on port number etc.

Answer (score 0):

I caution you that I have no experience with ns (Network Simulator). Clearly the variable $lnk has the value "" in the scope of the proc "o3" which is surely an "object" created by calling [new ...] at some point, though not necessarily in your code. Perhaps there is some initialization that you have to do so $ns_ or one of the other objects before you can attach a flow monitoring channel.

Answer (score -1):

[Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/) is an open source network protocol analyzer.
It should be able to analyze and display the communication flow of your application.

Comment: Even in 2009 Ethereal had been superseded by Wireshark